# How to re-emit socket.io event with new request body

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

Given i have emit:

```
socket.emit('getData', {
  id: buildingId,
  startTime,
  endTime,
  interval: 3000,
});
```

And listener:

```
socket.on(`getData.${buildingId}`, () => {...})
```

How propertly re-emit the same "getData" with other request body, and keep only one listener (not duplicate)?

i tried

```
socket.removeAllListeners();
socket.close();
socket.disconnect();
socket.connect();
```

no success so far.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the `emit` ([here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketemiteventname-args)) and `on` ([here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-api/#socketoneventname-callback)) methods, you should be able to emit a `getData` event with whatever body you want, and the event subscription shouldn't have to change.

You can setup you event subscription like this:

```
socket.on(`getData`, () => {...})
```

Then you can emit a `getData` event whenever you want with whatever body you want.

Example:

```js
socket.emit('getData', {
  id: buildingId1,
  startTime1,
  endTime1,
  interval: 3000
});

//...

socket.emit('getData', {
  id: buildingId2,
  startTime2,
  endTime2,
  interval: 10000
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. unfortunately, WebSocket server is settled up to emit events in this format `getData.${buildingId}`, so if I want to emit `getData` with new   `buildingId`, my 'old' `on` obviously will not get new data. For me, it looks like I have to somehow 'stop' \ 'cancel' my `socket.on(`getData.${buildingId}` and trigger it again. But  `socket.removeAllListeners();` doesn't work, instead, both new one and old one still triggered. Thanks.